# Does the formula $(x^n)' = nx^{n-1}$ fail for some value of $n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: calculus

It is well known that the formula $$\int x^n dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$

breaks down at $n=-1$ (we get a logarithm).

My question is, does there exist a value of $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ for which the formula $$\frac{d}{dx}x^n = nx^{n-1}$$

breaks down?

Comment: Don't think so. In fact, it should work for any $n \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: The difference is that with integration you divide by zero, while you only multiply with zero by differentiation. the latter case is no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a subtle way it somewhat fails for $n=0$ as $0\cdot x^{-1}$ is undefined at $x=0$. Apart from that (or if we agree to ignore isolated singularities) the rule holds for all $n\in\mathbb Z$ (and more, as Adriano comments).

Answer (score 2):

Per definition we know that for $x>0$ 
$$x^n = \exp( n \cdot \log(x))$$

Furthermore we only need the case $x>0$ as for $x<0 $ we can write $x=(-1)\cdot (-x)$ and $-x$ is greater than zero.

By chain rule we know that 
$$\frac{d}{dx} \exp(n\cdot \log(x))= n \cdot \frac{1}{x} \cdot \exp(n\cdot \log(x))$$
Simplifcation leads to 
$$n\cdot x^{n-1}$$
so it works for all $n\in \mathbb{R}$ where $x^n$ is defined.